# Spring batch job run only one instance at any time

Tags: spring-batch

Working on a spring boot application to be deployed in AWS ECS process. The application has 2 spring batch jobs, invoked in sequence by a service layer method triggered by cron. Job1 is tasklet based and Job2 is chunk based (may not be relevant here). Application data and the Batch metadata are saved into the same Postgres DB schema. With a single ECS process, everything is working fine as expected. I am using @EnableBatchProcessing annotation to set up the base configuration.

I would like to enable multiple ECS processes, but ensure that at any given time Job1 or Job2 is active in only one of the ECS processes. However, when Job1 is running in ECS1, it is okay to run Job2 in ECS2. Another requirement is to allow the service code that lauches the job to distinguish the programmatic stopping using ExitStatus or some other means.

To start with, I tried to use a JobExecutionListener::beforeStep and the JobExplorer + JobOperator to stop the job if another one is running. However, this throws exceptions like "relation batch_job_execution_params does not exist". It is rather baffling, since the table exists in the DB and was in fact created by Spring batch at startup. Also, without the JobExplorer/JobOperator, spring batch is accessing and maintaining data in its metadata tables without any issues. Tried adding SimpleJobOperator, JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor etc to no avail.

Why would it be that JobExplorer/JobOperator is throwing exception when rest of the batch system is able to access the metadata tables? Also, what would be the simplest approach to **atomically** identify if another instance of the job is running, either before launching the job or before executing the steps and then self abort? Can't use throttling, as the code outside the job also need to be able to understand this stopping and avoid certain actions of its own (like moving the file to done/invalid folder). Looking for a Spring batch solution. If not easy, I can switch to Quartz scheduler or some such tools. Hoping that Spring batch can achieve it as it has the shared status in the meta data tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a job instance as defined in the [Batch domain of Spring Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/domain.html#jobinstance) and an application instance. The description above is mixing the two.

If you correctly design your job instances (by carefully designing identifying job parameters), Spring Batch will ensure, thanks to the centralized job repository design, that a single job instance is executed at a time no matter how many application instances are executed in parallel.

Comment: I do understand the possibility of confusion. Sorry about that. I hoped I could make the distinction apparent by referring to them as ECS instance and Job instance. I have now changed ECS instance to ECS process in my question. 

I have runId + fileName parameters. Will 2 parallel executions with same fileName be considered as duplicate? Or will they both succeed because of the different runIds? 

Also, any pointers as to why `jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName)` is throwing exception of `batch_job_execution_params not found`. Related issue. Hence asking them together.

Comment: Also, just by using only the job name, is there a way to identify the presence of another running job execution, irrespective of the job parameters (whether different or unique), atomically? Asking because of the availability of jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName) method. Unfortunately, there are external factors beyond my control that disallows depending on the uniqueness of the parameter values for mutual exclusion.

Comment: No problem, thank you for the update. The file name should be enough if file names are unique (which should be the case if files are stored in the same file system). For example: file1 => jobInstance1, file2 => jobInstance2. With that in place, If jobInstance1 is successfully launched on ECS1, then spring batch will prevent jobInstance1 from running on ECS2 at the same time. For the error related to the job explorer, if the table is not found, it means the explorer is not configured with the correct datasource.